# add multiple command to cmd using java (apache.common.exec)

Tags: java, cmd, rsync

i need to add multiple command in java using apache.common.exec?

Code below will run window cmd and the path is C://Rsync> 
after i cd Rsync. i want to add another command like this inside java:

this -v -e ssh host@remoteserver:~/tmp /

ask me again if my questionis not clear. thanks

```
    try {


    String line = "cmd /c start cd C:\\Rsync";

    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);

    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    //watchdog
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);

    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
    }
    catch (Exception exc){     
       System.out.println("error" + exc);/*handle exception*/} 
    }


}
```

**Additional:**

i have try

```
    String line = "cmd /c start cd C:\\Rsync";

    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);

    cmdLine.addArgument("this -v -e ssh host@remoteserver:~/tmp / "); // i assume this is how we add extra command but wrong

    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
```

Comment: you mean use getruntime

Comment: Create a batch/shell script, dynamically if required and run it instead.  It should contain all the commands you want to execute...

Comment: MadProgrammer do you know where are the good site for me to read the documentation or information about how to create batch file or shell script

Comment: I want to know about "ssh host@remoteserver:~/tmp /"? Are you trying to setup rsync over ssh (or are you trying to run scp)?

Comment: Elliot, i want to run rsync over ssh. in my mind, i want to run rsync through cmd and put rsync command to copy my private key file to remote server.